# Can I approximate a complex number by its imaginary part, if real part is small compared to imaginary part?

Tags: complex-numbers

I have the following doubt. 
[image: complex no: Can we neglect real part if it is too small compared to imaginary part]

How do you explain this?

Here $j$ means $\sqrt{-1}$.

Comment: Is your "$j$" what most mathematicians call $\;i=\sqrt{-1}\;$ ?

Comment: I believe they're using quaternions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $\;j=i:=\sqrt{-1}\;$ :

$$ix+\frac{x^2}{a+ix}=\frac{-x^2+iax+x^2}{a+ix}=\frac{ax}{a+ix}i\xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{}a$$

The wrong part of your argument is that both summands in your original expression diverge when $\;x\to \infty\;$ , so you can't taka the limits separatedly.

Comment: $i = \sqrt{-1}$ ... ?

Comment: Oh, ok @Neal: I saw it in your editing. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$jx + \frac {x^2}{a+jx} = (jx + \frac {x^2}{jx}) + (\frac {x^2}{a+jx}  - \frac {x^2}{jx})$. As you've noted, $jx + \frac {x^2}{jx} = 0$, and for large $x$, $a$ is small compared to $a+jx$, from which it follows that $(\frac {x^2}{a+jx}  - \frac {x^2}{jx})$ is small compared to $\frac {x^2}{a+jx}$ or $\frac {x^2}{jx}$.

However, if you want to conclude that this sum is equivalent to $(jx + \frac {x^2}{jx})$, you have to show that $(\frac {x^2}{a+jx}  - \frac {x^2}{jx})$ is small compared to $(jx + \frac {x^2}{jx})$, which is false.